# Change Main Navigation Menu Font Colors On My Wordpress Website

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to make adjustments to the font colors in my wordpress navigation menu.

I have contacted the support team that created the theme (Cyberchimps), but since it is a free theme, they weren't in a position to offer much help other than to send me to a guide on CSS. I've done some CSS customization on other sites I have created, but this one is really giving me a hard time.

What I want to do is change the "current page" font color in the menu an orange, and make all other menu items white, instead of the grey they are now. I've tried using Firebug to find a solution, but had no luck with that either.Although it isn't critical, the grey is difficult to see, and I would prefer to change it.

Basically, I can't seem to locate which item controls the menu colors in the Stylesheet. If I could find that, I could make the adjustment easily (I think).

The website is http://rlsfind.com and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For current menu item

```
.navbar-inverse .nav .active > a {
   color: orange;
}
```

For other menu items

```
.navbar-inverse .nav > li > a {
   color: white;
}
```

You should learn about using your browser's developing tools. It's usually an easy way to see what styles are being applied where. For Chrome, [read here.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Comment: That worked like a charm, ovokuro, thank you! I attempted to track down the code that was controlling the colors, but was unable to find it. I used Firebug with Firefox, but it still wasn't clear to me what to change/add. It appears Chrome's dev tools is very similar to Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap.min.css Line 4201

```
    .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #111111
}
```

Change background color

Comment: I found where the code for the background was located, but I don't want to change that (at the moment). I do appreciate your input though. Thanks chop62

Comment: Ok thought it was the background you wanted to change i see you changed the font color to orange

Comment: I still appreciate you taking the time to respond chop62. Maybe someone else will see it that DOES need to change a background color, so it can still be very helpful. :=)